# Posting JSON from hidden form field

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I am intercepting a form post using jQuery. With the form fields I am creating a JSON object which is stored in a hidden form field. The value that is passed in to the form field is similar to the following:

```
{"Status" : "Closed", "Location" : "Glasgow", "Date" : "2012-02-15"}
```

But if I echo the object from the $_POST variable:

```
echo $_POST['JSON'];
```

It output's the following:

```
{\"Status\" : \"Closed\", \"Location\" : \"Glasgow\", \"Date\" : \"2012-02-15\"}
```

I have tried running this through *stripslashes()* and *urldecode()* but I have had no joy. I understand that I could just replace the back slashes with a replace function but thats a bit too much of a hack.

Has anyone came across this malfored JSON across post before?

**Note:** This is on the back end of a Wordpress site. I am unsure if that would cause this effect.

Comment: Can you check the post values sent by the browser? In chrome, press F12, open network tab and post your form. Click the request and note down Headers tab -> Form Data

Comment: I tried it it works fine
<input type="hidden" name="json" value='{"Status" : "Closed", "Location" : "Glasgow", "Date" : "2012-02-15"}'/>
and echo $_POST['json'];
gives proper output

Comment: is it possible that jQuery.submit() does some kind of url encoding? or escaping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you server has magic_qoutes_gpc 'on'. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.what.php)

Answer (score 0):

I came over the same problem once and all I did was using `JSON.stringify()` to store it as a "String" in my hidden Field and reading the output with `jquery.parseJSON()` method. Maybe this helps you ! With stringify you can also define a replacer for your JSON Object.
`var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);`

- http://www.json.org/js.html
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I can see how this would work, but I'd prefer not to have to parse using jQuery again after posting.

Answer (score 0):

Although my English is not good, but I see it is the issue of json in php, you can use json_decode do, can be transformed into an array

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility you have is to url-encode with `encodeURIComponent()` in javascript your json object and `urldecode()` in php the received object.

Be aware that encodeURIComponent() in js is not exactly the same as urlencode() in php and similarly decodeURIComponent() is not the same as urldecode(), but in most cases encoding in js and decoding in php and vice-versa works well.